# JPA Entity field reference OneToOne recursive

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting this error when I will **persist()** my entity. I think that the cause of the error is the relation, my idea is that FolderEntity (represents a virtual folder) can be stay inside another (only one) Then I created the reference to self (In the extended class, because all resources can be inside a folder, and folder is an resource)

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.editor.entity.FolderEntity.id in mappedBy of com.editor.entity.FolderEntity.folderId
```

This my main `Entity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    /** getter/setter **/

}
```

Then I extends it in my ResourceEntity Entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ResourceEntity extends Entity {

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = Lengths.NAME40, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = Lengths.DESCRIPTION1000, unique = false, nullable = true)
    private String description;

    @JoinColumn(name = "FOLDER_ID", updatable = true, nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id")
    private FolderEntity folderId;

    /** getter/setter **/

}
```

Finally, I am working with this entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "EDITOR_FOLDERS")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = FolderEntity.ALL_FOLDERS, query = "select f from FolderEntity f"),
        @NamedQuery(name = FolderEntity.FOLDER_BY_NAME, query = "select f from FolderEntity f where name = :name and resourceType = :resourceType") })
public class FolderEntity extends ResourceEntity {


    public static final String ALL_FOLDERS = "findAllFolders";
    public static final String FOLDER_BY_NAME = "findAllFoldersByName";

    @Column(name = "RESOURCE_TYPE", length = Lengths.CODE, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer resourceType;
    /** getter/setter **/

}
```

Anybodys help me to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a `@OneToOne` association here but a `@ManyToOne`.  After all, **many** resources can reside inside **one** folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the meaning of `mappedBy`: It does not reference the field that contains the ID (JPA is clever enough to find that one by itself), but it references another *XToOne* field that "owns" the mapping

> public abstract String **mappedBy**
>
> (Optional) The field that owns the relationship. This element is only specified on the inverse (non-owning) side of the association.

(from javadoc of [OneToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html))

In your case you don't need the `mappedBy` as you are on the owning side. And you should name the attribute `folder` as you are referencing no `ID` but an entity.

*Another remark*: Use an `enum` for `resourceType` if you intend to define the possible values in your application as constants.